# Alerts from indicator change

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm desperately trying to generate alerts from the indicator mentioned below. I get alerts in the form of plotchars with my query. But I just want an alert message for every change from long and short, i.e. the change from green to red. Unfortunately, my queries produce a lot of signals that can be used for a long or short. Does anyone have an idea how to run the query so that only a signal is issued for long or short?
Thank you for ideas

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test 35, overlay=true)

blackr=color.black /// for darkbackground change colour to yellow  see the next line or whatever
//blackr=yellow 
nolagwave=input(true, title="Check for pivot corrected WWV-LB wave or uncheck for original WWV-LB?")
pullback=input.int(3, minval= 1, maxval=5, title="Trend Detection Length")
wavechoice=1 // I have not included pips 
automan=input(true, title="click to calculate cumulative vol automatically a red zero means you must use manual method so unclick")
mul=input(0, title="input multiplication factor to show volume must be non zero, and only if box above is unclicked")
mult=mul>=1?mul:na
count=0
trend=0
wave=0
opp=0.0
tempvolup=0.0
tempvoldown=0.0
tvolup=0.0
tvoldown=0.0
tren=0
wavee=0
vol=0.0
up=0.0
dn=0.0
toppe=0.0
bottomme=0.0
toppeclose=0.0
bottommeclose=0.0
plottoppeclose=0.0
plotbottommeclose=0.0
cpvtoppe=0
cpvdbottomme=0
cpvhe=0.0
cpvh=0.0
multi=0.0


count:= nz(count[1]) + 1
tickid = request.security(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.regular)  //  syminfo.tickerid
lookbac= input(0, title="Look Back at volume per bar for estimating multi factor, if 0 lookback will use default values within script")
c1= 2  //input(2, minval=1, maxval=14,title="color of warning numbers, 1-red, 2-green, 3-blue, 4-navy, 5-yellow, 6-white, 7-orange, 8-maroon, 9-purple, 10-lime, 11-teal,11-aqua, 13-fuchsia, 14-black") //input(color=green, title="confirmed wave up")
c2= 1 //input(1, minval=1, maxval=14, title="color of error number - volume incorrect, check mult factor and adjust")
c4= 2  //input(2, minval=1, maxval=14, title="color of wave up")
reder= 1   //input(1, minval=1, maxval=14, title="color of wave down")
linew=input(5, title="wave line width")
renkochrt= false //input(false, title="Renko chart?")
errn= c2==1? color.red:c2==2? color.green: c2==3?color.blue: c2==4? color.navy: c2==5? color.yellow: c2==6?color.white: c2==7?color.orange:c2==8?color.maroon:
             c2==9? color.purple: c2==10?color.lime:c2==11?color.teal:c2==12?color.aqua:c2==13?color.fuchsia:color.black
periods= renkochrt and timeframe.isdaily?4000:renkochrt and timeframe.isweekly?400:renkochrt and timeframe.ismonthly?400:renkochrt?4000: (timeframe.period=="1"?4000: timeframe.period=="2"? 3000: timeframe.period=="3"?2000:timeframe.period=="4"?2000:timeframe.isintraday?200:timeframe.ismonthly?12:timeframe.isweekly?26:timeframe.isdaily?400:200)

greenr= c4==1? color.red:c4==2? color.green: c4==3?color.blue: c4==4? color.navy: c4==5? color.yellow: c4==6?color.white: c4==7?color.orange:c4==8?color.maroon:
             c4==9? color.purple: c4==10?color.lime:c4==11?color.teal:c4==12?color.aqua:c4==13?color.fuchsia:color.black

wn= c1==1? color.red:c1==2? color.green: c1==3?color.blue: c1==4? color.navy: c1==5? color.yellow: c1==6?color.white: c1==7?color.orange:c1==8?color.maroon:
             c1==9? color.purple: c1==10?color.lime:c1==11?color.teal:c1==12?color.aqua:c1==13?color.fuchsia:color.black

redr= reder==1? color.red:reder==2? color.green: reder==3?color.blue: reder==4? color.navy: reder==5? color.yellow: reder==6?color.white: reder==7?color.orange:reder==8?color.maroon:
             reder==9? color.purple: reder==10?color.lime:reder==11?color.teal:reder==12?color.aqua:reder==13?color.fuchsia:color.black



mov = close>close[1] ? 1 : close<close[1] ? -1 : 0
trend:= (mov != 0) and (mov != mov[1]) ? mov : nz(trend[1])
isTrending = (ta.rising(close, pullback) or ta.falling(close, pullback))
wave:=(trend != nz(wave[1])) and isTrending ? trend : nz(wave[1])


//////////////////////////new criteria to resolve lag ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                             
opp:=wave== wave[1] and close>close[20] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==19 ?20: 
     wave== wave[1] and  close>close[19] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==18 ?19:wave== wave[1] and  close>close[18] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==17 ?18:
         wave== wave[1] and close>close[17] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==16 ?17:wave== wave[1] and  close>close[16] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==15 ?16:
             wave== wave[1] and  close>close[15] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==14 ?15:wave== wave[1] and  close>close[14] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==13 ?14:
                 wave== wave[1] and close>close[13] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==12 ?13:wave== wave[1] and close>close[12] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==11 ?12:
                     wave== wave[1] and close>close[11] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==10?11:wave== wave[1] and close>close[10] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==9 ?10:
                         wave== wave[1] and close>close[9] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==8?9:wave== wave[1] and close>close[8] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==7?8:
                             wave== wave[1] and close>close[7] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==6?7:wave== wave[1] and close>close[6] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==5 ?6:
                                 wave== wave[1] and close>close[5] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==4?5:wave== wave[1] and close>close[4] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==3?4:
                                     wave== wave[1] and  close>close[3] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==2 ?3:wave== wave[1] and close>close[2] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==1?2:
                                         wave== wave[1] and  close>close[1] and wave==-1 and opp[1]==0?1:
                                             wave== wave[1] and close<close[23] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-22 ?-23:wave== wave[1] and close<close[22] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-21 ?-22:
                                                 wave== wave[1] and close<close[21] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-20 ?-21:wave== wave[1] and close<close[20] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-19 ?-20:
                                                     wave== wave[1] and close<close[19] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-18 ?-19:wave== wave[1] and close<close[18] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-17 ?-18:
                                                         wave== wave[1] and close<close[17] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-16 ?-17:wave== wave[1] and close<close[16] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-15 ?-16:
                                                             wave== wave[1] and close<close[15] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-14 ?-15:wave== wave[1] and close<close[14] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-13 ?-14:
                                                                 wave== wave[1] and close<close[13] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-12 ?-13:wave== wave[1] and close<close[12] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-11 ?-12:
                                                                     wave== wave[1] and close<close[11] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-10 ?-11:wave== wave[1] and close<close[10] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-9 ?-10:
                                                                         wave== wave[1] and close<close[9] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-8 ?-9:wave== wave[1] and close<close[8] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-7 ?-8:
                                                                             wave== wave[1] and close<close[7] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-6 ?-7:wave== wave[1] and close<close[6] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-5 ?-6:
                                                                                 wave== wave[1] and close<close[5] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-4 ?-5:wave== wave[1] and close<close[4] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-3 ?-4:
                                                                                     wave== wave[1] and close<close[3] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-2 ?-3:wave== wave[1] and close<close[2] and wave==1 and opp[1]==-1?-2:
                                                                                         wave== wave[1] and close<close[1] and wave==1?-1:0
                             

tempvolup:= opp==1?volume:opp>1?volume + nz(tempvolup[1]):0
tempvoldown:=opp==-1?volume:opp<-1?volume + nz(tempvoldown[1]):0
tvolup:= wave!=wave[1]?nz(tempvolup[1]):na
tvoldown:=wave!=wave[1]?nz(tempvoldown[1]):na
volumeup=0.0
volumeup:=wave!=wave[1] and nz(tvolup)>0 ? (nz(tvolup[0])+volume) : wave==wave[1] and wave==1 ? nz(volumeup[1]) + volume:volume
volumedn=0.0
volumedn:=wave!=wave[1] and nz(tvoldown)>0 ? (nz(tvoldown[0])+volume) : wave==wave[1] and wave==-1? nz(volumedn[1]) + volume:volume




cd=(((wave==wave[1] and wave==1) or wave==1) and opp[0]<0)  
cu= (((wave==wave[1] and wave==-1) or wave==-1) and opp[0]>0) 
su= ((wave==wave[1] and wave==1) or wave==1 ) and opp[0]==0
sd= ((wave==wave[1] and wave==-1) or wave==-1) and opp[0]==0

s=wave!=wave[1]
c=wave==wave[1]
vu=volumeup
vd=volumedn
tu=tempvolup
td=tempvoldown
uc=c and cd[1] and su // up continue
dc=c and cu[1] and sd // down continue
ds=s and cu[1] and su // up switch direction
us=s and cd[1] and sd // down switch direction



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////original Lazy Bear WWV_LB  /////////////////////
shovol=input(false, title="show volume?")
//lbwvv= input(false, title="WWV-LB use with Renko charts")
trendDetectionLength=pullback  //input(2, title="WWV-LB lookback x closes use 1 with Renko charts")

movm = close>close[1] ? 1 : close<close[1] ? -1 : 0
tren:= (movm != 0) and (movm != movm[1]) ? movm : nz(tren[1])

isTrnding = ta.rising(close, trendDetectionLength) or ta.falling(close, trendDetectionLength) 
//// use trend and istrending to determine if wave is continued or reversed
wavee:=(tren != nz(wavee[1])) and isTrnding ? tren : nz(wavee[1])
//countr= wave!= wave[1]?1: 1 + nz(countr[1])
vol:=wavee==wavee[1] ? (nz(vol[1])+volume) : volume
up:=wavee == 1 ? vol : 0
dn:= wavee == 1 ? 0 : vol
volumeupe= nz(up[0])==0 and nz(up[1])!=0?nz(up[1]):na
volumedne= nz(dn[0])==0 and nz(dn[1])>0?nz(dn[1]):na
//////////////////  end of Lazy Bear WWV ///////////////////////////

showmulti= mul==0 and automan==false?true:false 
// //count= nz(count[1]) + 1
calcmult=automan==true?true:false
lookback=lookbac==0?periods:lookbac


toppe:= nz(up[0])==0 and nz(up[1])!=0?nz(close[1]):na

bottomme:= nz(dn[0])==0 and nz(dn[1])!=0?nz(close[1]):na

toppeclose:= nz(up[0])==0 and nz(up[1])!=0?nz(close[1]):na
      
bottommeclose:= nz(dn[0])==0 and nz(dn[1])!=0?nz(close[1]):na

plottoppeclose:=toppe?toppeclose:plottoppeclose[1]
plotbottommeclose:=bottomme?bottommeclose:plotbottommeclose[1]
alertcondition(toppe, title='a top confirmed', message='WWV wave top confirmed!')
alertcondition(bottomme, title='a bottom confirmed', message='WWV wave bottom confirmed!')

// plotvolup1=  ct==-1?(volup[1]- lvolup[1]):na  //maxpivottf==true and
plotvolup= nolagwave ==true?(sd and us and cd[1]?volumeup[1]-tempvoldown[1]:su[1] and sd?volumeup[1]:na):volumeupe

cpvabs=plotvolup>=.00000001 and plotvolup<.0000001?-7:plotvolup>=.0000001 and plotvolup<.000001?-6:plotvolup>=.000001 and plotvolup<.00001?-5:plotvolup>=.00001 and plotvolup<.0001?-5:plotvolup>=.0001 and plotvolup<.001?-4:
     plotvolup>=.001 and plotvolup<.01?-3:plotvolup>=.01 and plotvolup<.1?-2:plotvolup>=.1 and plotvolup<1?-1: plotvolup>=1 and plotvolup<10  ?0:plotvolup>=10 and plotvolup<100?1:plotvolup>=100 and plotvolup<1000  ?2:plotvolup>=1000 and plotvolup<10000 ?3:
         plotvolup>=10000 and  plotvolup<100000?4:plotvolup>=100000 and  plotvolup<1000000?5:
             plotvolup>=1000000 and plotvolup<10000000  ?6:plotvolup>=10000000 and plotvolup<100000000  ?7:plotvolup>=100000000 and plotvolup<1000000000  ?8:plotvolup>=1000000000 and  plotvolup<10000000000?9:plotvolup>=10000000000 and  plotvolup<100000000000?10:
                 plotvolup>=100000000000 and  plotvolup<1000000000000?11:plotvolup>=1000000000000 and  plotvolup<10000000000000?12:plotvolup>=10000000000000 and  plotvolup<100000000000000?13:plotvolup>=100000000000000 and  plotvolup>=1000000000000000?14:
                     plotvolup>=1000000000000000 and plotvolup<10000000000000000  ?15:plotvolup>=10000000000000000 and plotvolup<100000000000000000  ?16:plotvolup>=100000000000000000 and plotvolup<1000000000000000000  ?17:
                         plotvolup>=1000000000000000000 and plotvolup<10000000000000000000  ?18:plotvolup>=10000000000000000000 and  plotvolup<100000000000000000000?19:plotvolup>=100000000000000000000   ?20:na
cpv=cpvabs>=19 and wavechoice==3?1:cpvabs
cpvtoppe:=toppe?cpv:nz(cpvtoppe[1])

plotvoldown= nolagwave?(su and ds and cu[1]?volumedn[1]-tempvolup[1]:su and sd[1]? volumedn[1]:na):volumedne
cpvdabs=plotvoldown>=.00000001 and plotvoldown<.0000001?-7:plotvoldown>=.0000001 and plotvoldown<.000001?-6:plotvoldown>=.000001 and plotvoldown<.00001?-5:plotvoldown>=.00001 and plotvoldown<.0001?-4:plotvoldown>=.0001 and plotvoldown<.001?-3:
     plotvoldown>=.001 and plotvoldown<.01?-3:plotvoldown>=.01 and plotvoldown<.1?-2:plotvoldown>=.1 and plotvoldown<1?-1:plotvoldown>=1 and plotvoldown<10  ?0:plotvoldown>=10 and plotvoldown<100?1:plotvoldown>=100 and plotvoldown<1000  ?2:plotvoldown>=1000 and plotvoldown<10000 ?3:
         plotvoldown>=10000 and  plotvoldown<100000?4:plotvoldown>=100000 and  plotvoldown<1000000?5:
             plotvoldown>=1000000 and plotvoldown<10000000  ?6:plotvoldown>=10000000 and plotvoldown<100000000  ?7:plotvoldown>=100000000 and plotvoldown<1000000000  ?8:plotvoldown>=1000000000 and  plotvoldown<10000000000?9:plotvoldown>=10000000000 and  plotvoldown<100000000000?10:   plotvoldown>=100000000000 and  plotvoldown<1000000000000?11:plotvoldown>=1000000000000 and  plotvoldown<10000000000000?12:plotvoldown>=10000000000000 and  plotvoldown<100000000000000?13:plotvoldown>=100000000000000 and  plotvoldown>=1000000000000000?14:
                 plotvoldown>=1000000000000000 and plotvoldown<10000000000000000  ?15:plotvoldown>=10000000000000000 and plotvoldown<100000000000000000  ?16:plotvoldown>=100000000000000000 and plotvoldown<1000000000000000000  ?17:
                     plotvoldown>=1000000000000000000 and plotvoldown<10000000000000000000  ?18:plotvoldown>=10000000000000000000 and  plotvoldown<100000000000000000000?19:plotvoldown>=100000000000000000000   ?20:na
cpvd  =cpvdabs==19 and wavechoice==3?1:cpvdabs

k=cpvd>20 or cpv>20?true:false
cpvdbottomme:=bottomme?cpvd:nz(cpvdbottomme[1])



cpvhe:=(timeframe.isdaily or timeframe.period=="4H")and count>=10 and count<= 30?nz(ta.highest(cpvtoppe,20))> nz(ta.highest(cpvdbottomme,20))? 
     nz(ta.highest(cpvtoppe,20)): nz(ta.highest(cpvdbottomme,20)): (timeframe.isdaily or timeframe.period=="4H") and (count>= 30 and count<200) ?-11:
         nz(ta.highest(cpvtoppe,lookback))> nz(ta.highest(cpvdbottomme,lookback))? nz(ta.highest(cpvtoppe,lookback)):
             nz(ta.highest(cpvdbottomme,lookback))



cpvh:= ((timeframe.isdaily or timeframe.period=="4H") and cpvhe==-10 and (count<=30 or count>200)) or ((timeframe.isdaily or timeframe.period=="4H") and (count>= 30 and count<200) and 
     cpvhe==-11) or ((not timeframe.isdaily or timeframe.period!="4H") and cpvhe==-10) ?nz(cpvh[1]):cpvhe


multi:= calcmult ? math.pow(10,(cpvh-2)):math.pow(10,((wavechoice==1 or wavechoice==4?mult:wavechoice==3?mult-10:mult-10)-2)) 
change= multi!=nz(multi[1])?true:false

arreg=plotvolup/multi
// limited to 1 in next line
ar=calcmult?arreg>=1000?arreg/10:arreg: showmulti and wavechoice==2?(cpv)+10:(wavechoice==1 or wavechoice==4) and showmulti?cpv: wavechoice==3 and showmulti?cpv+10: arreg>=1000?arreg/10:arreg //   arreg //(arreg<1?arreg*10:arreg>=1000?arreg/10:arreg)

y=ar<1?0:na
A3i=math.round((math.round(ar)-5)/10)*10
A3= math.round(ar)-A3i
A2i=(math.round(((A3i/10)-5)/10))*10
A2= A3i/10<10? A3i/10: ar<10?0:A3i/10-A2i
A1i= math.round((A2i/10-5)/10)*10
A1= A2i/10<10?A2i/10: A3i<10? 0:A2i/10-A1i
T= A1i/10>0 and A1i/10<10?A1i/10:na

//blackr=cpv<=-1 and toppe?red:cpv>=0 and toppe?black:cpv<=-1 and bottomme?red:cpv>=0 and bottomme?black:na // yellow


alertcondition(toppe or bottomme, title='a top or bottom  confirmed', message='Weis wave top or bottom confirmed!')

//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==1,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1 ,text="\n1\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==2,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n2\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==3,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n3\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==4,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n4\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==5,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n5\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==6,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n6\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==7,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n7\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==8,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n8\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  toppe and A1==9,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n9\n\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar( shovol and  toppe and A2==0 and A1!=0,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n0\n\n", textcolor= blackr)

//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==1,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n1\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==2,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n2\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==3,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n3\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==4,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n4\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==5,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n5\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==6,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n6\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==7,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n7\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==8,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n8\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A2==9,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n9\n\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==0,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n0\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==1,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n1\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==2,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n2\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==3,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n3\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==4,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n4\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==5,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n5\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==6,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n6\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==7,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n7\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==8,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n8\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and toppe and A3==9,location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n\n9\n", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and (not calcmult and toppe and (arreg)>=1000 and not mult==0) or k   or
     //( calcmult  and toppe and cpvhe==-11) or (calcmult and change) or (showmulti and cpv<0) or (showmulti and cpv>=0) , 
         //location=location.abovebar, offset=-1,text="\n0",textcolor= (arreg)>9999 or k 
         //or  ( calcmult and change) ?errn:(arreg)>999 ?wn:na) // and change //or (showmulti and cpv<0)

//label.new(bar_index[1], toppe+1 , style=label.style_none, text="Vol " + tostring(round(ar))) // plotting for version 4 also need line 259 above 229 to 258 should be hidden
ardreg=plotvoldown/(multi)
ard=calcmult? ardreg>=1000?ardreg/10:ardreg:  showmulti and wavechoice==2?(cpvd)+10:(wavechoice==1 or wavechoice==4) and showmulti?cpvd: wavechoice==3 and showmulti?cpvd+10:ardreg>=1000?ardreg/10:ardreg   //ardreg //(ardreg<1?ardreg*10:ardreg>=1000?ardreg/10:ardreg)

yd=ard<1?0:na
A3id=math.round((math.round(ard)-5)/10)*10
A3D= math.round(ard)-A3id
A2id=(math.round(((A3id/10)-5)/10))*10
A2D= A3id/10<10? A3id/10: ard<10?0:A3id/10-A2id
A1id= math.round((A2id/10-5)/10)*10
A1D= A2id/10<10?A2id/10: A3id<10? 0:A2id/10-A1id
Td= A1id/10>0 and A1id/10<10?A1id/10:na

//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==1,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n1", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==2,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n2", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==3,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n3", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==4,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n4", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==5,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n5", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==6,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n6", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==7,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n7", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==8,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n8", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A1D==9,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n9", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and  bottomme and  A2D==0 and A1D!=0,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n0", textcolor= blackr)

//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==1,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n1", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==2,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n2", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==3,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n3", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==4,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n4", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==5,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n5", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==6,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n6", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==7,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n7", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==8,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n8", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A2D==9,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n9", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==0,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n0", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==1,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n1", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==2,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n2", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==3,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n3", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==4,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n4", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==5,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n5", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==6,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n6", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==7,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n7", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==8,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n8", textcolor= blackr)
//plotchar(shovol and bottomme and  A3D==9,location=location.belowbar,offset=-1,text="\n\n\n9", textcolor= blackr)

//plotchar(shovol and (bottomme and (ardreg)>=1000 and not mult==0) or k or  ( calcmult  and bottomme and cpvhe==-11) or ( calcmult and change) or (showmulti and cpvd<0) or (showmulti and cpvd>=0) ,
     //location=location.belowbar, offset=-1,text="\n\n\n\n0",textcolor= (ardreg)>=9999 or k or  ( calcmult and change)  ?
         //errn:(ardreg)>=999 ?wn:na) //or (showmulti and cpvd<0)
// label.new(bar_index[1], bottomme-1,  style=label.style_none, text="Vol  " + tostring(round(ard))) // plotting for version 4 also need line 308 above 277 to 306 should be hidden
plot(nolagwave==true?(su or sd?close[0]:na):((wavee!=wavee[1] and wavee>0?close[1]: wavee!=wavee[1] and wavee<0?close[1]:na)) , color= nolagwave and sd  ?color.red:(nolagwave and su)?color.green:
     (nolagwave==false and su)?color.red:color.green, offset=nolagwave?0: -1  , linewidth=linew)


//test_color= nolagwave and sd  ?color.red:(nolagwave and su)?color.green:(nolagwave==false and su)?color.red:color.green, offset=nolagwave?0: -1
test_color= nolagwave and sd  ?color.red : color.green, offset=nolagwave?0: -1

//go_l = nolagwave==true ? (su or sd ? close[0] : na) : ((wavee!=wavee[1] and wavee>0 ? close[1] : wavee!=wavee[1] and wavee<0 ? close[1] : na))

//mov = close>close[1] ? 1 : close<close[1] ? -1 : 0
//trend:= (mov != 0) and (mov != mov[1]) ? mov : nz(trend[1])
//isTrending = (ta.rising(close, pullback) or ta.falling(close, pullback))
//wave:=(trend != nz(wave[1])) and isTrending ? trend : nz(wave[1])

//plottoppeclose:=toppe?toppeclose:plottoppeclose[1]
//plotbottommeclose:=bottomme?bottommeclose:plotbottommeclose[1]
//alertcondition(toppe, title='a top confirmed', message='WWV wave top confirmed!')
//alertcondition(bottomme, title='a bottom confirmed', message='WWV wave bottom confirmed!')


// Long
plotchar(
     
      //nolagwave and sd  
      //nolagwave==true?(su or sd?close[0]:na):((wavee!=wavee[1] and wavee>0?close[1]: wavee!=wavee[1] and wavee<0?close[1]:na))
      //test_color == color.green
      //nolagwave==true and
      //su or sd//?close[0]
      //(mov != 0) and (mov != mov[1]) //? mov : nz(trend[1])
      mov != 0 and mov != mov[1] //? mov : nz(trend[1])


      , "Buy", "X", location.bottom, color.lime, size = size.tiny)


// Short
plotchar(
     
      //nolagwave==false //and 
      //su
      //test_color == color.red
      //nolagwave==true
      //plottoppeclose

      mov != 0 and mov == mov[1] //? mov : nz(trend[1])
   

      , "Sell", "X", location.top, color.red, size = size.tiny)
```